# How to delete from database selected item in ListView in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, select

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and Visual Studio-C# 2010 Ultimate.
I have a ListView and some items in it. I want to delete an item when I selected it and I clicked the button but I could not write the SqlCommandtext and I could not find the select event for ListView.

Comment: You have onItemDeleting event where you can delete the row

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give an example please.  for example  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Products where ProductID='" ???"'", connection);  what will I write ??? part?

Comment: Are you talking about using WPF and MVVM? Or are you talking about an ASP.NET listview?

Comment: read from here <br> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdeleting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Deleting selected data from database using listview c#

```
private void btnlvdeleterow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      foreach (int i in Listview2.SelectedIndices)
        {
            string test = Listview2.Items[i].Text;
            Listview2.Items.Remove(Listview2.Items[i]);
            SQLiteCommand conn = new SQLiteCommand();
            conn.Connection = DbClass1.GetConnection();
            string del = "delete from UserData where UserName='" + test + "'";
            int result=dbclass1.ExecuteAndReturn(del);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a SelectedIndex property available with the ListView. When you click the button, pass this index and then your Sql query will be something like
delete from Products where ProductID =  'obj.ID' where obj is obtained from listView.SelectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void listview1_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
     //This retrieves the selected row 
     ListViewItem  item= listview1.Items [e.ItemIndex];

     //  Fetch the control for ProductId using findControl
      int productId=int.Parse((item.Findcontrol("ProductID") as TextBox).Text);

     //then use this column value in your sqlcommand

   using( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
        ("delete from Products where ProductID=@ProductId", connection  ))
    {
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ProductId", productId));
     //Then execute the query
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= listView2.Items.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    string test = listView2.SelectedItems[j].SubItems[1].Text;
                    string MyConnection2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
                    string Query = "delete from TABLE_NAME where COL_NAME='" + test + "'";
                    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
                    MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
                    MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
                    MyConn2.Open();
                    MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();

                    while (MyReader2.Read())
                    {
                    }
                    MyConn2.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");
                   // txtCustomerName.Text = test;
                    //listView2.Items.Remove(listView2.Items[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Formatting is a bit of and some insides to your code would be good.

Answer (score -1):

The Event you are looking for should be ListView.ItemSelectionChanged
where the eventArgs contains the selected Items

Comment: The question states the delete is done upon a button click, not on changing the selected item.